# Rails render object in json with model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render the user model along with the posts model, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the syntax for it would be

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def map_locations
    @posts = Post.where.not(location: [nil, ""])
    render :json => @posts.as_json(only: [:topic, :location, :latitude, :longitude],)
  end
```

Output:

```
[{"topic":"Garret ATX","location":"Hornitos, CA, USA","latitude":37.5021592,"longitude":-120.238241}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{"user_name":"Randy","topic":"Garret ATX","location":"Hornitos, CA, USA","latitude":37.5021592,"longitude":-120.238241}
```

The user model has @user.user_name which is the one I need for each post. 
How do I render the user associated with each post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this works

```
def map_locations
  @posts = Post.where.not(location: [nil, ""])
  render :json => @posts.as_json(:only => [:topic, :location, :latitude, :longitude], :include => {:user => {:only => :user_name}})
end
```

Please check the [apidock](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) for more details.